# Get JSON object dropdown menu SAPUI5

Tags: json, xml, sapui5

I created dropdown menu SAPUI5, but I can't find detail when I press the menu list. etc: when I click, show the name from JSON object.

json :

```
    dropdownMenu: {
        kepesertaan:[
            {
                name: "Menu1",
                icon: "sap-icon://crop",
                sub: [
                    { 
                        name: "Submenu1-1",
                        icon: "sap-icon://create-session"   
                    },
                    { 
                        name: "Submenu1-2",
                        icon: "sap-icon://create-form" 
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Menu2",
                icon: "sap-icon://detail-view",
                sub: [
                    { 
                        name: "Submenu2-1",
                        icon: "sap-icon://add-activity" 
                    },
                    { 
                        name: "Submenu2-2",
                        icon: "sap-icon://action" 
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Menu3",
                icon: "sap-icon://delete",
                sub: [
                    { 
                        name: "Submenu3-1",
                        icon: "sap-icon://add-favorite" 
                    },
                    { 
                        name: "Submenu3-2",
                        icon: "sap-icon://add-document" 
                    }
                ]
            }               
        ]
}
```

XML fragment:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified">
        <u:Menu items="{kepesertaanmodel>/}" id="menuEventingKepesertaan"
            itemSelect="handleMenuItemPressKepesertaan">
            <u:MenuItem
                text="{kepesertaanmodel>name}"
                icon="{kepesertaanmodel>icon}">

                <u:Menu items="{kepesertaanmodel>sub/}" id="submenuEventingKepesertaan"
                        itemSelect="handleSubMenuItemPressKepesertaan">
                    <u:MenuItem
                        text="{kepesertaanmodel>name}"
                        icon="{kepesertaanmodel>icon}"/>
                </u:Menu>
            </u:MenuItem>
        </u:Menu>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

in controller:

```
handleMenuItemPressKepesertaan: function(oEvent) {
    MessageToast.show(oEvent.getParameter("item").getModel("kepesertaanmodel").getProperty("/").name);
}
```

I want show the name from the JSON object when click press, but failed. How to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understand the question you want to take a property from the current context of the selected item.

You can try to:

```
oEvent.getParameter("item").getBindingContext().getProperty("name");
```

Comment: with that code show error "Cannot read property 'getProperty' of undefined"

Comment: Could you please paste your code in this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/sudetahoxe/1/edit?html,output) so I can check further?

Comment: [source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ht6OjY_2FjQjNsc2lLYW9LMU0/view?usp=sharing) <-- link.
I upload to google drive because use xml and js file